# A-Frame searpte image inside of a div is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe

The image has been assigned correctly all the directories are correct but the image does not show up
My main theory for it not working is the fact that the div is outside of the a-scene where the images are assgined. The images not working are the FPpoint images as already stated the images can be found the paths are correct but they do not show up in the div. The image in the div does get the correct source but it doesnt show up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--https://medium.com/designerrs/how-to-create-a-virtual-tour-using-a-frame-164941fea573 --> 
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>360&deg; Image</title>
        <meta name="description" content="360&deg; Image - A-Frame">
        
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.5.1/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
          AFRAME.registerComponent('hotspots',{
            init:function(){
                this.el.addEventListener('reloadspots',function(evt){
                
                //get the entire current spot group and scale it to 0
                var currspotgroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.currspots);
                currspotgroup.setAttribute("scale","0 0 0");
                
                //get the entire new spot group and scale it to 1
                var newspotgroup=document.getElementById(evt.detail.newspots);
                newspotgroup.setAttribute("scale","1 1 1");
              });
            }
          });
          AFRAME.registerComponent('spot',{
            schema:{
              linkto:{type:"string",default:""},
              spotgroup:{type:"string",default:""},
              minmap:{type:"string", default:""}
            },
            init:function(){
              
              //add image source of hotspot icon
              this.el.setAttribute("src","#hotspot");
              //make the icon look at the camera all the time
              this.el.setAttribute("look-at","#cam");
              
              var data=this.data;
              
              this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
                //set the skybox source to the new image as per the spot
                var sky=document.getElementById("skybox");
                sky.setAttribute("src",data.linkto);
                //set minimap to correct image
                var img=document.getElementById("imag");
                img.setAttribute("src",data.minmap);

                var spotcomp=document.getElementById("spots");
                var currspots=this.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
                //create event for spots component to change the spots data
                spotcomp.emit('reloadspots',{newspots:data.spotgroup,currspots:currspots});
              });
            }
          });
        </script>
        <style>
            .column {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            .row:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }
            .button {
                width: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                color: white;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                border: 1px solid rgb(167, 165, 165);
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
            }
            .menubutton {
                background-color: rgb(0, 155, 180);
                width: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                border: 1px solid rgb(167, 165, 165);
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
                color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
            
            } 
            .menubutton:hover {
                border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
                font-size: 18px;
                text-align: end;
                width: 100%;
            }
            </style>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:xd_Signature msdt:dt="string"></mso:xd_Signature>
    <mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Editor msdt:dt="string">Doug Parr</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Editor>
    <mso:Order msdt:dt="string">13300.0000000000</mso:Order>
    <mso:ComplianceAssetId msdt:dt="string"></mso:ComplianceAssetId>
    <mso:TemplateUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:TemplateUrl>
    <mso:xd_ProgID msdt:dt="string"></mso:xd_ProgID>
    <mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Author msdt:dt="string">Doug Parr</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_Author>
    <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x010100EA9D30DC7ABABD44B55EDE237B8B05A2</mso:ContentTypeId>
    <mso:_SourceUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SourceUrl>
    <mso:_SharedFileIndex msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SharedFileIndex>
    </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    </xml><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
                <a-assets>
                    <img id = "point1" src="images/SOC.JPG">
                    <img id = "point2" src="images/Corridor01.JPG">
                    <img id = "point3" src="images/CL2.JPG">
                    <img id = "point4" src="images/CL3.JPG">
                    <img id = "FPpoint1" src="images/Point01.PNG">
                    <img id = "FPpoint2" src="images/Point02.PNG">
                    <img id = "FPpoint3" src="images/Point03.PNG">
                    <img id = "FPpoint4" src="images/Point04.PNG">
                      
                      
                <img id="hotspot" src="hotspot.png">
                </a-assets>
                
                <a-entity id="spots" hotspots>
                  <a-entity id="group-point1">
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point2;spotgroup:group-point2;minmap:#FPpoint2" position="9 1 10"></a-image>
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point3;spotgroup:group-point2;minmap:#FPpoint2" position="-10 1 -5"></a-image>
                  </a-entity>
                 
                 <a-entity id="group-point2" scale="0 0 0">
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point1;spotgroup:group-point1;minmap:#FPpoint1" position="10 0 -8"></a-image>
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point3;spotgroup:group-point3;minmap:#FPpoint3" position="0 0 10"></a-image>
                    
                  </a-entity>
          
                  <a-entity id="group-point3" scale="0 0 0">
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point2;spotgroup:group-point4;minmap:#FPpoint4" position="10 0 3"></a-image>
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point4;spotgroup:group-point4;minmap:#FPpoint4" position="-10 0 -3"></a-image>
              
                  </a-entity>
          
                  <a-entity id="group-point4" scale="0 0 0">
                    <a-image spot="linkto:#point3;spotgroup:group-point3;minmap:#FPpoint3" position="0 0 -10"></a-image>
           
                  </a-entity>
          
                </a-entity>
                
                <a-sky id="skybox" src="#point1"></a-sky>
                
                
                <a-entity id="cam" camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls>
                  <a-entity cursor="fuse:true;fuseTimeout:2000"
                            geometry="primitive:ring;radiusInner:0.01;radiusOuter:0.02"
                            position="0 0 -1.8"
                            material="shader:flat;color:#ff0000"
                            animation__mouseenter="property:scale;to:3 3 3;startEvents:mouseenter;endEvents:mouseleave;dir:reverse;dur:2000;loop:1">
                  </a-entity>
                </a-entity>
                
              </a-scene>
              <div style="position:relative;">
             </div>
              <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:1500px; z-index:1000;">
                <div class="row">
                  <img id="imag" src="#FPpoint01" width="400" height="200" />
                 
                </div>
            </div>
              <div style="position:relative;">
              </div>
            <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1000;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Home" onclick ="document.location='Test Home Page.html'"/> 
                        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="About Us" onclick ="document.location='About us.html'"/> 
                        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="UTC Website" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.utcsheffield.org.uk/olp/'"/> 
                        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Tour Builder" onclick ="document.location='Tour Builder.html'"/> 
                        <input class="menubutton" type="button" value="Staff Log In" onclick ="document.location='Staff Log In.html'"/>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div is outside of the a-scene, just put the url there, instead of the id:
**images/Point01.PNG** instead of **#FPpoint01** (this id isn't even correct btw, the correct id is **#FPpoint1**).